# Get getTotalsAction result data

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I tried updating the cart using JS and summary container is updating properly. But I want to update the quantity of the item. So basically I have added a custom button in `checkout/cart` page. When this button is click I add one product into the cart. Now this product is fix and the quantiity added per click is fix. Now everything is working just fine including the summary container. But I want to update the Quantity field in the form-cart container. But I don't know how to do that.

I found out that `getTotalsAction` contains the total that  want but I don't know how to retrieve this result. I'm thinking of looping through the result to update the quantity value. How can I do this?

Note: I don't want a page refresh.

Below is my code

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/ui'    
], function ($, getTotalsAction, cartCache, totalsProcessor, quote, customerData) {
'use strict';

 $.widget('mage.poundToCart', {
     _create: function () {          
       this.processAddCart();       
    },
    processAddCart: function(form) {
        formData = new FormData(form[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {  
              var deferred = $.Deferred();
              getTotalsAction([], deferred); // <--- I want to retrieve this value
              return false;
            }
       });
    }
 });
```

How can I do this?

I tried this link but this does not apply in my situation as there is no validate response that I get. So I just want to refresh the cart form page like the image below

[image]

So basically I want to update the quantity field since adding the product is done via Ajax

Comment: I don't think even magento has written anything for the qty update, magento refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log the value inside this function in this way:

```
var deferredAction  = getTotalsAction([], deferred);
console.log(deferredAction);
```

then you have :
[image]

Now you can use for example 'success' like this :

```
deferredAction.success(function(){
     // you can do whatever you want here
     //$('.ccfidelity').attr('disabled',false);
});
```